# why am I not getting an "used uninitialized" warning from gcc in this trivial example?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

Once again a stupid uninitialized variable error in [How to fix this segmentation error in a sequence inverting program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465136/how-to-fix-this-segmentation-error-in-a-sequence-inverting-program).

So I was going to repeat the "please use `-Wall` flags" comment, but when I tested the code against warnings, I found no warnings reported to my great surprise.

So I trimmed it down to this below (this code makes no sense for execution purposes but it illustrates what I want to show):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int i,len=12;

  /* printf("%d\n",i); */

  while(i!=len-1)
  {

    i++;
    len--;
  }

 return 0;
 }
```

when compiling it using `gcc` 4.7.3 and 6.2.1 using

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

I get no warnings, whereas `i` is blatantly not initialized before using in the `while` loop.

Now if I uncomment the `printf` statement I get:

```
warning: 'i' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

So why is the warning issued when passing `i` to `printf` but not in the `while` test?

(It's different of [gcc failing to warn of uninitialized variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705880/gcc-failing-to-warn-of-uninitialized-variable) because in my case, there's are no branches)

(Sounds like a bug, but it's so trivial that I wonder if I'm not missing something huge.)

Comment: why not assign  i = 0?

Comment: Do you obtain different results if you force specific versions of the language standard via -std=....?

Comment: @SirDarius nope. same for c99, same for compiling with g++.

Comment: Commenting `i++` from while loop shows `[-Wuninitialized]`  waring. Have no idea why.

Comment: @Sma good point. Now that's beginning to look like a bug. That said, gcc is optimistic when reporting warnings: when it reports a warning, there's a _real_ problem. But it can fail to report some.

Comment: @usr yes, looks very much like it. Well, in my case, it's guaranteed that the control flow reaches the `while`. Not the case in the other question.

Comment: It looks like the `-Wuninitialized` warning is simply not attached to check counter variables within the `while` loop itself. I was surprised to not see a warning here. Intriguing catch.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't know the GCC codebase, but had a case a while ago where **increasing** the optimization level was needed to make a warning appear, so I assume some "unholy" design where the same code is sometimes used for optimization and analysis for warnings...

Comment: Does moving the `printf()` to *after* the `while`-loop affect the warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to say it's a *bug*, because `gcc` mixes up code for optimization and for creating warnings, which is even documented for this particular warning:

> `-Wuninitialized`
>   Warn if an automatic variable is used without first being initialized or if a variable may be clobbered by a setjmp call.
>   [...]
>   **Because these warnings depend on optimization, the exact variables or elements for which there are warnings depends on the precise optimization options and version of GCC used.**

(from GCC docs [Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), emphasis mine)

You found an IMHO very silly case here. Try `-O1` and you'll get an unexpected warning:

```
warn.c: In function ‘main’:
warn.c:13:6: warning: ‘i’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     i++;
      ^
```

So, `gcc` still misses the first uninitialized use, but finds the second one! Try `-O0` or `-O2` and the warning is again gone...

You could still try to file a bug about this. Note `clang` gets it right:

```
warn.c:10:9: warning: variable 'i' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
  while(i!=len-1)
        ^
warn.c:6:8: note: initialize the variable 'i' to silence this warning
  int i,len=12;
       ^
        = 0
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: there is already a bug for this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18501

Comment: I'm seriously considering dropping gcc now... thanks.

Comment: @bolov interesting ;) But the way gcc documents this warning makes it very difficult to say it's indeed a bug...

Comment: @bolov: from your link "Hey guys, this year will be the 10 year anniversary of this bug.  We should order cake!" :) now I'm hungry. Thanks for the answers everyone. Looks that gcc creators don't care too much about UB :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre we missed the party. It was 3 years ago :)

Comment: @bolov last year Santa Claus, now gcc... desillusions always ...