# Terminal does not show the warnings of a program...How to see them in terminal?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, warnings, gnome-terminal

This is a simple program which i wrote it with vim editor:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b, c ;
    a=(b+c+11)/3;
    cout << "x=" << a;
    cout << "\n";
        return 0;
}
```

We can see the warnings in visual studio in windows:

```
...error(s), 2 warning(s)
...\test1.cpp(7) : warning c4700: local variable 'b' used without having been initialized 
...\test1.cpp(7) : warning c4700: local variable 'c' used without having been initialized
```

But, When we use gnome-terminal, we can't see warnings:

```
SSS@SSS:~/.cpp$ g++ test1.cpp -o test1
SSS@SSS:~/.cpp$ chmod +x test1
SSS@SSS:~/.cpp$ ./test1
x=10925
SSS@SSS:~/.cpp$
```

In terminal we just can see errors...

How to see these warnings?

Any command?to see warnings?

Comment: you need to enable them: `g++ -Wall test1.cp -o test1`

Comment: Wrong language! I've fixed.

Comment: [Best compiler warning level for C/C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399850/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual studio default warnings level is different from `g++` default warning level.

You need to enable the warnings (I suggest `-Wall`) to see them.

```
g++ -Wall test1.cpp -o test1
```

prints:

```
test1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test1.cpp:8:9: warning: 'b' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     a=(b+c+11)/3;
        ~^~
test1.cpp:8:9: warning: 'c' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

as the message suggests `-Wuninitialized` is enough for this kind of warnings, but I suggest you use `-Wall` for starters, and turn off the warnings that you don't need if you *really* need that on some legacy code, the best way being to enable extra warnings, and turn the warnings into errors so people have to fix them:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror ...
```

Also note that you cannot rely on this warning to detect *all* uninitialized variables. There are complex cases where the compiler cannot decide if it's initialized (see [why am I not getting an "used uninitialized" warning from gcc in this trivial example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465442/why-am-i-not-getting-an-used-uninitialized-warning-from-gcc-in-this-trivial-ex)). For that you need a more specialized tool like Valgrind.

Comment: I suggest `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g test1.cpp -o test1` to get even more warnings and an executable with debug info (in DWARF format)

Comment: Adding debug or not is hardly relevant to the current question (as relevant as optimization level for instance, which can affect the warnings...). I agree with `Wextra`, though. edited.

Comment: The newbie would want to debug his program

Comment: I thought that newbies _never_ debugged their programs that's why they end up posting here :). While I agree, this is a question about warnings, not "which are the best compilation options". It's probably covered in some other thread.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre maybe u r right... i agree i'm newbie in Cpp:) ... i like python... but i must learn C/C++ for college!... and i just start it right now:) 1 hour ago!   anyway thank you

Comment: good luck, and remember: python is excellent but isn't fast enough for some applications, and you sometimes have to reuse some C or C++ codes, so better get knowledge of all of them. Then use python when needed (for instance to run C programs in loops & exploit their results)

Comment: and yes, learn to use a debugger right away. Visual C++ debugger is system friendly enough. gdb needs a good interface or it's just horrible to work with.