# What exactly is the difference between blocks and loops?

Tags: c

**Code-1:**  No warnings - No errors ... everything works fine

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int r = 1;
    printf("using %d\n", r);

    for (int k = 1; k <= 2; k++)
    {
       int r = r * 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Code-2:**  Wrong

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int cnt = 1;
    printf("using %d\n", cnt);
    
    {
        int cnt = cnt * 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**compiler response:**

```c
'cnt' is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
       int cnt = cnt * 2;
```

So, I understand there is some difference between the `loop` and `block` in this case, but I am unable to figure out. Can anyone tell me how the `scope of a variable` works here?

Comment: cnt in the block is not assigned

Comment: @ArjunUS so is `r` in the loop

Comment: I think it has something to do with how compiler was designed. check this link [why am I not getting an “used uninitialized” warning from gcc in this trivial example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465442/why-am-i-not-getting-an-used-uninitialized-warning-from-gcc-in-this-trivial-ex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both have exactly the same problem i.e. `r` and `cnt` are self-initialized in respective programs.

This is potentially *undefined* because of use of uninitialized variables (which has indeterminate value) if they happen to have trap representation.

`gcc` happens to detect it one case and doesn't in the other case. `gcc` has `-Wuninitialized -Winit-self` options but it still doesn't detect the first case even with these options. Regardless, the issue remains (and the same) in both.

Comment: Could you explain why in the first case, at the end of `int r = r * 2;` statement, the value of `r` is 0 ? Is it because of the indeterminate value?

Comment: Yes, 0 can be an indeterminate value too. In general, *when* exactly using an uninitialized variable is undefined is immaterial - because there's no sane way to interpret that code/program (this is not to confused with objects with static storage who are guaranteed to be initialized to 0 even if initializers aren't provided e.g. global variables, `static int i;` anywhere, etc).

Comment: Makes sense. So to summarize how should the behavior of the first case be interpreted now if its not a compiler bug?

Comment: The outer scope variables aren't particularly relevant to the question because they are not visible in the inner scope due to declarations of `r` & `cnt` (variables with same name). It's not a compiler bug per se because compilers aren't required to issue diagnostics (warnings/errors) for undefined behaviours. Specifically, compilers are required to issue diagnostics for constraint violations; for others like UBs, programmers errors, etc they may warn to be helpful - but not required to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I have doubt, so what if I put ```printf("using %d\n", cnt);``` before the existing statement in the block, does this ```printf statement``` also cause undefined behaviour? I am asking is it valid to use outer scope variables in this block until another variable (with same name) is defined?

Comment: @SaiSreenivas Do you mean something like https://godbolt.org/z/Y8q8ME? Yes, the `printf` is OK here because at the point, there's just only one `cnt` (thus no overlapping scope involved).
But beware that [UB can time-travel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32132574/1275169) - if some parts of the program [unconditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18385020/1275169) exhibits UB, the whole program is said to contain UB.

Comment: In gcc this line generates a warning with `-Wshadow` but I can't find any way to detect the uninitialized state.